# How can I bulkify EmailMessage insert when sending mass SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I am having an issue with bulk sending bulk emails, that then insert as emailmessage, even if I do a bulk send of emails when it goes to insert the emailmessage it is doing a single insert for each emailmessage and then my trigger and logic on this object is hitting limits even though it's bulkified. So I am not properly bulk sending these emails? or do I need to move the logic to a queueable class that repeat smaller sizes until all the logic is done? or...?

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage [] singleEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(customobject__c co : colist){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    //set parameters
    singleEmails.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(singleEmails);
```

I'm guessing Salesforce is doing something like below when inserting emailmessages after I use `Messaging.sendEmail(listemails);`

```
for(SingleEmailMessage sem : emails){
    insert EmailMessage
}
```

To confirm the above I added a debug to emailmessage on the trigger to see how many times the trigger is being called to confirm that it is what's happening

```
trigger EmailMessage_Trigger on EmailMessage (after insert, after Update) {

    EmailMessage_HDL objHandler = new EmailMessage_HDL();
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        if(Trigger.isAfter)
        {
            system.debug('DEBUG EmailMessage Trigger');
            //logic in handler below is hitting limits in the single transaction
            objHandler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.newMap);
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) does state "When org preferences are set to save EmailMessage objects and a trigger is defined for EmailMessage objects, the trigger is fired for each SingleEmailMessage individually.". Salesforce (imo) has never been a great mass email tool, any specific reason you are using Apex to send them? How many are you likely to send?

Comment: Thanks for the information. The query that determines who is being sent the mass email needs to be done on demand and has things like cross object filters with some additional logic. The largest size of emails that can be sent is roughly only 300, but even with such a small number the "the trigger is fired for each SingleEmailMessage individually" will obviousely run into limits very quickly even though my emailmessage trigger logic only has 5 queries.

Comment: I was able to modify the code slightly to send a limited amount of emails in a queueable job that endlessly chains itself until all are sent, and initally testing works. While this is ugly I think is hard to recommend a complete overhall of the current solution unless the number of emails dramatically changes (if it does I would no longer support the current solution)

Comment: Considering bulk scenario, I can suggest a hack/workaround. Say you wanna send 200 mails about some anouncement or similar event. Have To email with some noreply@company.domain and put others in bcc. With that you'd consume less single email limit as well.

Comment: Thanks but BCC is not compliant/secure enough in this situation and the email needs to be individually addressed to each contact for proof of additional compliance reasons

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Michael you are setting up the same "to address" in the code, that's why Salesforce is sending bulk email as 10 times internally, as per the documentation it says -
The single email, mass email, and list email limits count duplicate email addresses. For example, if you have johndoe@example.com in your email 10 times that counts as 10 against the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest that instead of sending the emails directly in apex trigger you instead create an object record instance and then use flow to send the emails.  Have found this method to be more bulk safe and it also creates auditable data.